# Terminating SBT build build elegantly with simple error message

Tags: sbt

I have an *SBT* build for a project that requires *Java 8* and I have also included some *Java 8* features (mainly `java.time` package elements) in the build itself. If I attempt to build the project on an earlier *JVM* (such as 1.7), I get a whole load of errors and exceptions when I run the `sbt` command.

So, I decided to add an `initialize` property to detect the *JVM* in use and terminate the build with an elegant message if the *JVM* in use wasn't at least version 8. Of course, this only works if I use it to build the builder (if I put it in `./build.sbt`, then I still get errors if using *JVM* 1.7 or earlier because the `java.time` elements are not present). So I have a `./project/build.sbt` file that contains the following:

```scala
initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  if (!scala.util.Properties.isJavaAtLeast ("1.8")) {
    sys.error ("My project requires Java 8 or later")
  }
}
```

This works, but rather inelegantly. If I run `sbt` with *Java 7*, then I get the following output from the build:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: My project requires Java 8 or later
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at $ed9be51e9ab4a59b3b3b$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(C:\Users\me\Documents\src\myproject\project\build.sbt:55)
        at $ed9be51e9ab4a59b3b3b$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(C:\Users\me\Documents\src\myproject\project\build.sbt:47)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:177)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:67)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:76)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] My project requires Java 8 or later
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

If I place the same code in an empty `./build.sbt` file, and run using *Java 7* then I simply get:

```
[error] My project requires Java 8 or later
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

That is, I don't get the exception message and stack trace.

Is there a way to make the build build exit more elegantly, so that I get output of the latter form rather than the former?